# Iverson Bracket / Conditional Sum of a string

Tags: notation

I'm trying to turn calculations that I've been using on a data set into mathematic notation to write it down in a research paper.

One of my calculations creates a factor that determines how often a certain value (in this case the geographic location of $r$), appears in a string $s$.

As a definition I wrote:

$\Gamma$ is defined for a release $r$ as the number of its occurrences in the sequence $s$ divided by count of all its elements $n$. After readingh trhough various articles I based my notation to cases where people used Iverson brackets ([Mathematical notation for a conditional sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/mathematical-notation-for-a-conditional-sum)) and came up with following:

\begin{equation}
\Gamma(r_{iso}) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \Big[ s_{i} = r_{iso}\Big]}{n}
\end{equation}
\begin{align*}
\text{where}\\~r_{iso} &= \text{release origin of r} \\ 
  s_{i} &= \text{sequence of all accounted geographic locations}
\end{align*}

Reading this, would a math ninja scream out of agony or does this seem about right? Are there other / better ways of expressing this definition?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's cumbersome as a definition. You can use $|\{s_i:s_i=r_{iso}\}|$ or $\#\{s_i:s_i=r_{iso}\}$ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn’t bother me, though if I took this approach I’d probably write it

$$\Gamma(r_{iso})=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n[s_i=r_{iso}]$$

instead. Unfortunately, quite a few people are still unfamiliar with Iverson brackets, so it would probably be better to use a more familiar alternative. Perhaps the simplest is

$$\Gamma(r_{iso})=\frac1n\big|\{i:s_i=r_{iso}\}\big|$$

or

$$\Gamma(r_{iso})=\frac{\big|\{i:s_i=r_{iso}\}\big|}n\;,$$

depending on person preference.