# Mathematical notation for 1 if true, 0 if false function

Tags: notation, boolean-algebra

It is quite embarrassing, but I completely forgot the generally accepted short notation of writing $1$ if predicate $P$ is true, $0$ if predicate $P$ is false.

I'm pretty sure something like that exists because I saw a notation expressing this in a few presentations and it was mostly coherent.

The operator looked somewhat like this $\|P\|$, but it definitely did not share the symbol with norm.

I am asking because I plan to write something like $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\|P_i\|$ and I think that writing it with if-else notation would be ugly.

Comment: The [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).  I would post this as an answer, but I suspect that this is a duplicate question.  If I can't find a good dupe target, I'll come back and answer this in a bit.

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99344/)?  In particular, [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/99347/468350) seems to get the job done.